# How to find Label Controls inside a Form and its nested Panels?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I need to change the background color of all the Labels inside a Form and nested Panels.

I tried this code but it only changes the color of the Labels that are inside the Form, not all the Labels inside the Panels.

```
  For Each Label As Control In Me.Controls
      If Label.GetType.ToString = "System.Windows.Forms.panel" Then
          Label.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
      End If
  Next
```

My Form looks like this:

[image: Form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a simple recursive method that parses all Controls in a Form.

When a Control in the collection is of type `Label`, set the `BackColor` property.
When the Control contains other Controls, parse its `Controls` collection to see whether it contains some Labels; when one is found, set its `BackColor`.

Call the method:

```
SetLabelsColor(Me, Color.AliceBlue)
```

Recursive method:

```
Private Sub SetLabelsColor(parent As Control, color As Color)
    If (parent Is Nothing) OrElse (Not parent.HasChildren) Then Return
    For Each ctl As Control In parent.Controls.OfType(Of Control)
        If TypeOf ctl Is Label Then
            ctl.BackColor = color
        Else
            If ctl.HasChildren Then
                SetLabelsColor(ctl, color)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want to modify the Labels that are inside Panels and not other containers, you could modify the condition that triggers the recursion:

```
If (TypeOf ctl Is Panel) AndAlso (ctl.HasChildren) Then
    SetLabelsColor(ctl, color)
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer which is shared by Jimi is quite good for the question. But I'd like to share a more general answer which shows how you can use [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), [Iterator Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/iterator?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [Enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) extension methods.

#### Get All Descendant Controls (children, children of children, ...)

You can create an extension method to list all descendants of a control. When writing this method, you can easily take advantage of Iterator functions and Recursive functions to return an `IEnumerable<Control>`:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module ControlExtensions

    <Extension()> 
    Public Iterator Function DescendantControls(c As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
        For Each c1 As Control In c.Controls
            Yield c1
            For Each c2 As Control In c1.DescendantControls()
                Yield c2
            Next 
        Next
    End Function

End Module
```

Then you can use the extension method to get all descendants and use `OfType` to filter to specific type of control:

```
For Each c In Me.DescendantControls().OfType(Of Label)
    c.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
Next
```