# Debugging VB.NET Studio gets halted

Tags: winforms, checkbox, controls, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to check some CheckBoxes programatically.
I read this post to do it.
[How To Get Control Property by "String Name"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name)

My code:
**1)**

```
Dim FiltrosStr As String = AnswerX.Substring(7)
Dim Filt13() As String = FiltrosStr.Split(",")

If Filt13.Length >= 2 Then
Dim Filt1 = Filt13(0)
Dim Filt3 = Filt13(1)

x = 1
For Each XBit As Char In Filt1

    Dim ChkName As String = "Filt" & x.ToString & "xxEvtVerChk"

    Dim ChkX As CheckBox = Me.Controls.Find(ChkName, True).FirstOrDefault()'<-Halt here

    If XBit = "1" Then
        ChkX.Checked = True
    Else
        ChkX.Checked = False
    End If
    x += 1
    If x > 6 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

**2) Also tried**

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim FiltrosStr As String = AnswerX.Substring(7)
Dim Filt13() As String = FiltrosStr.Split(",")

If Filt13.Length >= 2 Then
Dim Filt1 = Filt13(0)
Dim Filt3 = Filt13(1)

x = 1
For Each XBit As Char In Filt1

    Dim ChkName As String = "Filt" & x.ToString & "xxEvtVerChk"
    Dim ChkX As CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls(ChkName), CheckBox)'<-Halt here            
    If XBit = "1" Then
        ChkX.Checked = True
    Else
        ChkX.Checked = False
    End If
    x += 1
    If x > 6 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I just need to check or uncheck some checkboxes that are inside a three level TabPage
Form-> TabPage-> TabPage-> TabPage-> GroupBox-> CheckBox

The 12 Check Boxes have almost the same name, only changes one number in the middle of it names.

I don't understand what I doing wrong and why even the IDE get halted.
The only way to stop it is by closing the session or restart Windows.

Comment: `Me.Controls` does not contain the CheckBoxes you're after directly: they're inside some other container. You could adapt one of recursive method you can find here: [How to find Label Controls inside a Form and its nested Panels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684650/how-to-find-label-controls-inside-a-form-and-its-nested-panels/53685043#53685043) to search for your CheckBoxes. Or save somewhere the name of the Container (the GroupBox) and access its `Controls` collection directly.

Comment: @Jimi I just changed the code to use the name of the GroupBox that contains the Check Boxes and it work; but I don´t understand, if I set the property ***searchAllChildren*** to True I thought that that means that it will search inside all the controls. So, What's the purpose of that property?

Comment: I just tried to make you change your code `Dim ChkX As CheckBox = Me.Controls.Find(ChkName, True).FirstOrDefault()` is not actually correct. That  method returns a collection of **Controls**. If you want to return a specific Control Type, you need to cast Control to the actual Type (something that is shown in linked answers). You should have:  `Dim ChkX As CheckBox = Me.Controls.Find(ChkName, True).OfType(Of CheckBox).FirstOrDefault()`. Then, there's the thing related to the TabPages and how their handled. Long story.