# Is there any way to create a global function to clear TextBoxes?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I was wondering if there is any way to create a class with a global function/method/sub that upon
calling it will clear some of the textboxes of the form. How can i handle the different number of textboxes
each forms has?

The current code clears only the pre-defined 2 boxes. Thank you.

```
Public Class ClearElements

    Public Sub CLEAR_TEXT(ByVal text1 As TextBox, ByVal text2 As TextBox)
        text1.Clear()
        text2.Clear()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You could recursively go through all the controls in the form and in case of type = Textbox clear it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form

Comment: I 've done that before. It clears all the boxes of the form. I am talking about the case where some boxes have to be untouched and some to cleared.

Comment: You'd need to test each textbox for whatever condition you need to meet, to determine if you'd like to clear it then.

Comment: What are the conditions that some get cleared and some don't?

Comment: Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53689480/3110834) and then: `Me.DescendantControls().OfType(Of TextBox).ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) x.Clear())`

Answer (score 3):

We have this:

> You could recursively go through all the controls in the form and in case of type = Textbox clear it.

But then the plot thickens:

> I've done that before. It clears all the boxes of the form. I am talking about the case where some boxes have to be untouched and some to cleared.

The solution here is two parts. First, create the recursive method as suggested like this:

```
Public Sub ClearText(root As Control)
    For Each ctrl As Control In Root.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then ctrl.Text = String.Empty
        ClearText(ctrl)
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

or this:

```
Public Sub ClearText(root As IEnumerable(Of Control))
    For Each ctrl As Control In root
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then ctrl.Text = String.Empty
        ClearText(ctrl.Controls)
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Second, on your form, use a container like `Panel`, `GroupBox`, `FlowLayoutPanel`, etc for the TextBox controls you need to clear. The key is *all of the TextBox controls you need to clear — and none of the ones you want to keep — should be in same common container*. Once that is done, you can pass the container to one of the above methods. If this messes with your layout, you can have a small number of containers for sets of controls on different areas of the form and call the function just a few times.

Remember, `Panel` controls can be styled to leave no visible artifacts on the parent form at all, and used entirely for logical groupings. The second version of the method above will also allow you to create arrays or lists of the controls (or control containers) you care about.

Another way to control this is to inherit a custom control from TextBox. You don't even need to change anything. All that matters is the control is now a different type from a regular textbox, and so the recursive method can target your new control type instead of textbox.

Comment: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Control.ControlCollection' to 'IEnumerable(Of Control)'. I would hate to turn Option Strict off to use this. ClearText(ctrl.Controls.Cast(Of Control)) seems to fix it but is this correct?

Comment: I forget that `ControlCollection` is brain-dead and does not implement `IEnumerable(Of Control)`. The best solution is probably overloading the method.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it.

You can add the TextBoxes to a List, and clear each item in the list

```
Private ReadOnly someOfTheTextBoxes As New List(Of TextBox)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    someOfTheTextBoxes.Add(TextBox1)
    someOfTheTextBoxes.Add(TextBox2)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each t In someOfTheTextBoxes
        t.Clear()
    Next
End Sub
```

Or make this method

```
Public Sub CLEAR_TEXT(textboxes As IEnumerable(Of TextBox))
    For Each t In textboxes
        t.Clear()
    Next
End Sub
```

and call it with your list of TextBoxes

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    CLEAR_TEXT(someOfTheTextBoxes)
End Sub
```

or make an array on the spot and pass it in

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    CLEAR_TEXT({TextBox1, TextBox2})
End Sub
```

If you are interested in recursion at all, here are some extensions I have which could help

```
Module Extensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function ChildControls(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
        Return ChildControls(Of Control)(parent)
    End Function
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function ChildControls(Of TControl As Control)(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of TControl)
        Dim result As New List(Of TControl)
        For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TControl Then result.Add(CType(ctrl, TControl))
            result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of TControl)())
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function ForEach(Of TSource)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), action As Action(Of TSource)) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
        For Each item As TSource In source
            action(item)
        Next item
        Return source
    End Function

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function ForEach(Of TSource)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), action As Action(Of TSource, Integer)) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
        For i As Integer = 0 To source.Count() - 1
            action(source.ElementAt(i), i)
        Next
        Return source
    End Function
End Module
```

Clear all textboxes recursively

```
Me.ChildControls(Of TextBox).ForEach(Sub(t) t.Clear())
```

Or ForEach on your list

```
someOfTheTextBoxes.ForEach(Sub(t) t.Clear())
```

Comment: Using [`Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/yield-statement?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) makes the code cleaner. For example, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53689480/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yield would work too, but it's not just cleaner code, the code will work differently i.e. the controls will not be iterated immediately, rather upon the subsequent LINQ call. I can see how it fits better in the spirit of IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using For in some cases.

First is to know for what do you need Textboxes or any component.
Second is to know if Textboxes (or any other component) will be inside Form (root) or inside others components like panels, groupoxes, tabPages… and if them will be inside of others.

**Example1:** Form – GroupBox(x) – TabControl(y) – TabPage(z) – TextBox(n)

**Example2:** Form --- TextBox(x)

**Example3:** Form – GroupBoox(x) – Panel(y) – TextBox(n)

Etcetera.

You may to create some anidated subs/functions to complete something more elaborated. There are two important things:

1. Path of the component (see previous examples)
2. Number of the component. If you follow Example3, maybe could be this:

Form1 – GroupBox2 – Panel1 – TextBox3

Important: These are names of the components, and you need must be enumerated all of them.

The easy way to do what you are asking is:

```
Public Sub CountTextBoxesAndClear(ByVal FormName As String, Optional ByVal myObject As Object = Nothing)
    Dim ArrayTextBoxName() As String
    Dim myTextBox As New TextBox
    Dim nTBOX As Integer

    'Path of component
    If myObject = Nothing Then myObject = My.Application.OpenForms.Item(FormName)
    'Bucle
    For i As Integer = 0 To myObject.Controls.Count - 1
        If myObject.Controls(i).GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
            'Counting
            nTBOX += 1
            'Redim array
            ReDim Preserve ArrayTextBoxName(nTBOX)
            'Get Component
            ArrayTextBoxName(nTBOX) = "TextBox" & nTBOX
            'Get Path
            myTextBox = myObject.Controls.Item(ArrayTextBoxName(nTBOX))
            'myTextBox = myObject.Controls.Item("TextBox" & nTBOX) '<< the same of above line
            Try
                'Clear TextBoxes
                myTextBox.Clear()
            Catch ex As NullReferenceException
                'A TextBox is Null, no error message
            End Try
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

FormName is the name of Form, with quotes, for example “Form1”.

myObject is the object that contains textboxes, if Textboxes are inside of a Panel named Panel1, you must write Panel1 (without quotes).

Try/Catch: Maybe you need to have Textbox1, TextBox2, Textbox4, Textbox5, AnotherTextBox1, AnotherTextBox2.

And you call your sub:

```
CountTextBoxesAndClear("Form1")
```

If TextBoxes are into a Panel named Panel1:

```
CountTextBoxesAndClear("Form1", Panel1)
```

You must to have the total of textboxes but only clear (or do any action) only for TextBoxes named TextBox[x].

Try/Catch manage the error because TextBox3 does not exist. However, the correct way is Textbox1, TextBox2, Textbox3, Textbox4, AnotherTextBox1, AnotherTextBox2 and put limits in your sub/function.

For example:

```
Public Sub CountTextBoxesAndClear(ByVal FormName As String, Optional ByVal myObject As Object = Nothing, Optional byval start as integer = 0, Optional byval finish as integer = 0)
    […tracatra…]
    For i As Integer = start To finish
        […tratra…]
    Next
End Sub
```

And this is how to call:

```
CountTextBoxesAndClear("Form1", Nothing, 1, 4)
```

And now, you can investigate a little bit about how create subs/functions to know correct paths of components, and get contents and properties of TextBoxes, Labels, Comboboxes, checkboxes…

**Additional info:**

If you are working in VisualStudio, you know that if you change a name of component, all of code is changed automatically. This is a big problem if you are using *start/finish* vars as numbers because, you must to change manually all start/finish values in functions when you need to add/remove or move positions, for example:

```
CountTextBoxesAndClear("Form1", Nothing, 8, 12)
```

Now you need to add a new TextBox just in the eight position and move one. Your sub looks like this:

```
CountTextBoxesAndClear("Form1", Nothing, 9, 13)
```

You can create a simply function that convert the name of the component to integer (this function is only for two digits (0 to 99):

```
   Public Function ObjToInt(ByVal IntObject As Object) As Integer
        If IntObject IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim ref As Integer = Val(IntObject.Name.Substring(IntObject.Name.Length - 2))
            If ref = 0 Then
                ref = Val(IntObject.Name.Substring(IntObject.Name.Length - 1))
            End If
            Return ref
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function
```

And your sub may be written like this:

```
CountTextBoxesAndClear("Form1", Nothing, ObjToInt(TextBox9), ObjToInt(TextBox13))
```

Comment: Or you could get the number at the end of a control name with a one liner: `Return Integer.Parse(IntObject.Name.Reverse().TakeWhile(Function(c) Integer.TryParse(c)).Reverse())` and it will take any number of digits... and you might as well make it take a Control instead of Object for some strong typing

Comment: This method is going to fail when you have TextBox1 and TextBox01

Comment: Yes, it fails because we need a constant, in this case the name of component: “TextBox”. This is a string.
If we use “TextBox01” the name is “TextBox0” and its number. All names must be equal and only change the number of the sequence. I assuming that to enumerate any object “01” is not a number because 01 is 1 for people but for computer is other thing.
Thanks for your comment, your notes and your answer. I’m learning about that.

Comment: If I knew I could have 10+ controls, I'd use TextBox01, 02, etc. because they will sort by name up to 99. TextBox2 > TextBox10 alphabetically TextBox02 < TextBox10

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your awesome solutions.

I finally figured it out using ParamArray

```
 Public Sub CLEAR_TEXTBOXES(ParamArray arr_textboxes() As TextBox)
    For Each textbox As TextBox In arr_textboxes
        textbox.Clear()
    Next
End Sub
```

Then i call class using whatever textbox i want,

```
CLS_CLEAR_TEXTBOX.CLEAR_TEXTBOXES(TextBox1, TextBox2, Textbox7)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more shorter method.
Use ParamArray and Linq.

```vb
Public Sub CLEAR_TEXT(ParamArray text As TextBox())
        text.ToList().ForEach(Sub(s) s.Clear())
End Sub
```