# How to remove all pictureboxes from a form at runtime

Tags: vb.net

I have dynamically created pictureboxes but I wish to remove all of them during runtime later in the program. I have tried the following vb code:

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In Form.Controls
    If TypeOf (c) Is PictureBox Then
        Form.Controls.Remove(PictureBox)
    End If
Next
```

The issue with this code is `PictureBox` as that is not a named object. I simply want to remove ALL pictureboxes from the form.

Comment: See these two recursive methods: [How to find Label Controls inside a Form and its nested Panels?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53684650/7444103)

Comment: `Form.Controls.Remove(PictureBox)` should be `Form.Controls.Remove(c)`.

Comment: @preciousbetine It should be `c.Dispose()`. It'ld remove the control from the Controls collection and the app won't leak like hell. Calling `Controls.Remove()`, especially when the control is a PictureBox, is the worst thing one can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Dim pb = TryCast(ctrl, PictureBox)
        If pb IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(pb)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
For Each pb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().ToArray()
    pb.Dispose()
Next
```

The `OfType` method does the filtering by type and so neatens the code a bit.  The `ToArray` call is so that you are not enumerating a collection that you are modifying within the loop.  The `Dispose` call is better than calling `Remove` because `Dispose` will implicitly remove but `Remove` will not implicitly dispose.

If you are done with the `Image` in the `PictureBox` then you ought to dispose it to, which you can neatly do like this:

```
For Each pb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().ToArray()
    pb.Image?.Dispose()
    pb.Dispose()
Next
```

That uses null propagation so it will not throw an `NullReferenceException` if the `Image` property is `Nothing`. If there's no chance of that anyway, just use a regular dot operator.  That null propagation is equivalent to this:

```
For Each pb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().ToArray()
    If pb.Image IsNot Nothing Then
        pb.Image.Dispose()
    End If

    pb.Dispose()
Next
```

Comment: @Bill435  This is what you should do. If your app creates/destroys PictureBox controls relatively frequently, it will have short life if you don't dispose of those objects/handles.