# Problem with Windows Form and Access Database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

First post here. I'm actually new to the world of programming and what I ask could look silly to many of you.
Anyway I'm trying to create a Form that will search into a Database the name you're looking for, showing a list of information about that person.

Problem comes when there's more than one person with that name in the database: in that case, the form only shows one of them. I wanted to add a button to get to the next result, but that's where I'm stuck.

I looked on the web for similar problems, but couldn't find any.

Here's my code, hope someone could help me
(please keep in mind I'm new and I don't know much about programming yet).
**Form1**:

```
Private Sub BtnCerca_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCerca.Click
    Dim trova As Boolean

    Try
        cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM persone WHERE nome = '" & txtSearch.Text & "' OR cognome = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
            dr = .ExecuteReader
        End With
        While dr.Read()
            txtId.Text = dr("id_persone").ToString
            txtNome.Text = dr("nome").ToString
            txtCognome.Text = dr("cognome").ToString
            txtDate.Text = dr("data_nascita").ToString
            txtNascita.Text = dr("luogo_nascita").ToString
            txtResidenza.Text = dr("luogo_residenza").ToString
            trova = True
        End While

        If trova = False Then Dim unused = MsgBox("UTENTE NON TROVATO!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        dr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call Connection()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnReset_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    ClearTextFields(Me)
End Sub

Public Sub ClearTextFields(ByVal parent As Control)
    For Each ctl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
            If ctl.Text.Trim() <> String.Empty Then
                ctl.Text = String.Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Module**:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module modConnection
    Public cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader

    Public Sub Connection()
        cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        With cn
            .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\dati_persone.mdb"
            .Open()
        End With
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: You'll be glad to know that it's all wrong. Isn't that awesome? So many things to fix... About the direct question: you're iterating the DataReader results, repeatedly setting the same TextBox controls, so, in the end, you'll see the data of the last record found. -- When you execute a `SELECT` query, you have to test `DataReader.HasRows` before iterating the results (if any). See the Docs about [DataAdapters and DataReaders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders) -- Search this Site (or Google it) about SQL Injection and Command Parameters.

Comment: Another important detail (more important with the Jet or ACE OleDb providers) is to avoid storing the Connection object  (and, actually, any other Data object) in a Field: when you need a Connection, create one, create the other related objects (Command, DataSet, DataAdapter, DataReader etc.) and Dispose() of them right after the current operation is completed. See also the Docs about disposing of disposable objects, the [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement/block.

Comment: The `ClearTextFields()` is also not correct. See the two code samples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53684650/7444103), in relation to recursive routines used to locate Controls in nested containers. You should also read the Docs about the [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) class and [DataBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings) in general.

Comment: `SELECT ALL` should be `SELECT id_persone, nome, cognome, data_nascita, luogo_nascita, luogo_residenza`.

Comment: @Jimi `While dr.Read()` is fine without checking `HasRows`. If there are no rows, dr.Read() immediately returns False.

Comment: @Andrew Morton ...unless you try to access a record because you didn't check and you assume it got *something* or you have, right after, a condition like: `If trova = False Then Dim...` using a local `bool`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake copy-pasting the code. It's actually `SELECT *` and not `SELECT ALL`

Comment: I forgot to mention the empty `Catch` block. Don't do that, you'll eat up the exception so you don't know that you got an exception and you keep going, like nothing happened. So something else will raised an exception further on because of an apparently unrelated problem. Or the application will just exit.

Comment: anyway thanks for the suggestion, I'm here to learn so I was sure it was full of mistake :D

Comment: @AresMuto What would you want to show to the user if there is more than one matching row? How does the user want to choose the correct row?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'd like to add two more buttons (Previous and Next) that will move through the different results (when there's more than one). Or if you have other suggestion or a better/easier solution, free to share it.

Comment: You can use the (already mentioned) BindingSource, which provides the MoveNext, MovePrevious, MoveFirst, MoveLast methods. Or add the results to a ListBox or a ListView or a DataGridView.

Comment: You could also do a "master-detail", where the master is a list of all query results - maybe limited to name - in a DataGridView, and then the detail is below, with the TextBoxes populated based on the entry selected from the DataGridView. Think Outlook with the Preview Pane turned on underneath the list of emails in the Inbox.

Answer (score 0):

In the form design view, drag and drop the `BindingNavigator` onto your form. You will find this in the Toolbox under the Data node. You can remove the + button and the X button by right clicking and choosing Delete from the context menu.

We will use a `DataTable` since that can be used as a `DataSource` for the `BindingSource`.

Keep your data objects local to the method where they are used so you can be sure they are closed and disposed. A `Using` block takes care of this for you. The `Using` block here includes both the connection and the command.

Always use parameters to avoid sql injection which can damage your database.

Create a `BindingSource` and set its `DataSource` to the `DataTable`. Then set the `BindingSource` property of the `BindingNavigator` you added to the form. Next add the `DataBindings` to each of your text boxes. The `.Add` method takes the name of the property to bind to, the `BindingSource`, and the field name.

That should do it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection("your connection string"),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * From persone Where nome = @nome Or cognome = @cognome;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nome", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSearch.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cognome", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSearch.Text
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Dim BdS As New BindingSource
        BdS.DataSource = dt
        BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = BdS
        txtId.DataBindings.Add("Text", BdS, "id_persone")
        txtNome.DataBindings.Add("Text", BdS, "nome")
        txtCognome.DataBindings.Add("Text", BdS, "cognome")
        txtDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", BdS, "data_nascita")
        txtNascita.DataBindings.Add("Text", BdS, "luogo_nascita")
        txtResidenza.DataBindings.Add("Text", BdS, "luogo_residenza")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```