# Parsing the form controls

Tags: vb.net, controls

I've written a small routine to change the `FlatStyle` property of all buttons in my form:

```
For Each item As Control In Me.ItemGroupBox.Controls
    If TypeOf (item) Is Button Then
        Dim _control As Button = CType(item, Button)
        _control.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup
    End If
Next
```

Is there a way to simplify this iterator?

Comment: Do you `Import System.Linq`? Then you can have `For Each item As Button In Me.ItemGroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()`. So you don't need to cast. If not, you can remove the brackets in `TypeOf (item)` :)

Comment: "all buttons in my form"  This will only get Buttons in your GroupBox.  If all buttons happen to be in the GroupBox then great, otherwise you'd need a recursive routine to find "all" buttons, even they are nested in other containers.

Comment: In case you need to find all Controls of a Type inside the Form Container, nested or not, see the two simple methods here: [How to find Label Controls inside a Form and its nested Panels?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53684650/7444103)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Will help me for sure! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this (as @Jimi gave you hints):

```vb
ItemGroupBox
  .Controls
  .OfType(Of Button)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(Sub(b) b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup)
```

### UPDATE

You could go further and create generic extension method for any `Control` object which will apply actions to its controls.

```vb
'// Extension method
Public Module ControlsExtension
  <Extension>
  Public Sub ProcessControls(Of T As {Control})(root As Control, action As Action(Of T))
    root.Controls.OfType(Of T).ToList().ForEach(action)
  End Sub
End Module

'// Process controls
Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
  ItemGroupBox.ProcessControls(Of Button)(Sub(b) b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup)
End Sub
```